# Accessing autowired beans in multiple classes

Tags: java

my question is how can I access bean in class X, that is autowired in class Y?

I'm using spring boot, I have 2 controllers:

```
@Controller
public class OwnerController {

    @Autowired
    StandardDaoAction<Owner> ownerDao;
```

and another one

```
@Controller
public class VisitController {

    @Autowired
    StandardDaoAction<Pet> petDao;
```

now I need to add StandardDaoAction ownerDao bean in VisitController class, but when I use simply autowired, I get exception, because multiple beans of the same class defined and spring does not know what to do. I tried somehow to distinguish them with @Qualifier, but it did not worked or I messed up with something.

It's pretty basic question but Im stuck with it and cant find the solution

ok So I ran into conclusion that the core problem is with my implementation of dao's and interface aka something is wrong with my usage of generics:

my interface :

```
public interface StandardDaoAction<T> {
    public T get(int id);
    public void remove(int id);
    public void add(T Type);
    public void update(T type);
    public List<T> getAll();
}
```

implementation of the interface by both classes:

```
@Repository
public class PetDaoImpl implements StandardDaoAction<Pet> {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public Pet get(int id) {
        return em.find(Pet.class, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remove(int id) {
        em.remove(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void add(Pet pet) {
        em.persist(pet);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Pet pet) {
        em.merge(pet);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<Pet> getAll() {
        return em.createQuery("from Pet").getResultList();
    }

}


@Repository
public class OwnerDaoImpl implements StandardDaoAction<Owner> {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public Owner get(int id) {
        return em.find(Owner.class, id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remove(int id) {
         em.remove(get(id));
    }

    @Transactional
    public void add(Owner owner) {
        em.persist(owner);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Owner owner) {
        em.merge(owner);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<Owner> getAll() {
        return em.createQuery("From Owner").getResultList();
    }

}
```

when I add:

```
@Controller
public class VisitController {

    @Autowired
    StandardDaoAction<Pet> petDao;

    @Autowired
    StandardDaoAction<Owner> ownerDao;
```

this is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'visitController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: pl.kaczynski.dao.StandardDaoAction pl.kaczynski.controller.VisitController.ownerDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [pl.kaczynski.dao.StandardDaoAction] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: ownerDaoImpl,petDaoImpl,vetDaoImpl
```

there is also vetDaoImpl because there is another controller:

```
@Controller
public class VetListController {


    @Autowired
    StandardDaoAction<Vet> vetDao;
```

which also implements the interface, as you can see above.

so As long as I have one bean that implements StandardDaoActions interface , it's working because it goes autowired by type, but when I add another autowired bean in different controller , the error occurs.

Comment: Show the exception. Problem is not the outowiring. The Problem is the Definition ob beans

Comment: `multiple beans of the same class defined` - show them, please.  `I tried somehow to distinguish them with @Qualifier` - show it, please.

Comment: you need to define `annotation` if you want to use multiple beans or use @qualifiar(someId)`

Comment: read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925681/spring-autowired-with-2-beans-of-the-same-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type erasure you will have two beans of type `StandardDaoAction`.

- inject either by the concrete type as `@Autowired private PetDaoImpl petDao`
- or use `@Autowired @Qualifier("petDaoImpl") private StandardDaoAction<Pet> petDao`