# Injecting 2 bean with same class name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a app 'app_test' which consists a class TestClass with @Service anotation. I have a library class 'lib_test' with bean in XML file with id=''TestClass'. Both are in different  package.

I m injecting @Service bean as follows

```
Import com.app.TestClass

    Class TestController
    {
    Private final TestClass testClass;

    @Inject
    TestController  (TestClass testClass)
    {
      This.testClass =testClass;
    }
    }
```

It should inject by type since they are in different package. But the controller is giving qualified bean not found.

I can resolve it by giving @Qualifier and giving name to @Service. But y is it needed? Since both are in different package it should autowire by type right? Or m missing some concept?

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925681/spring-autowired-with-2-beans-of-the-same-type

Comment: No. It's one with same package and different name. M talking about different package and same name.

Answer (score 1):

Although they are in different packages if they are of the same type Spring does not know which to use

I'd suggest marking any service class with `@Primary`.

```
package com.app.TestClass
@Primary
@Repository
public class TestClass implements XXX
```

This way it will be selected as the default autowire candididate, with no need to autowire-candidate on the other bean.

Also, rather than using `@Autowired @Qualifier`, I find it more elegant to use `@Resource` for picking specific beans.

Comment: They are not same type. Methods and everything are different just the bean name is same. And it is not giving duplicate it is giving as bean not found.

Answer (score 1):

I've always found this a strange limitation of Spring's standard bean naming convention.  It does not include the package part of the class in the name leading to duplicates in large projects when classes have the same name.

This is why I always configure Spring projects with a different `BeanNameGenerator`:

```
public class CustomAnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext extends AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext {
    private BeanNameGenerator qualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator = new QualifiedNameAnnotationBeanNameGenerator();

    @Override
    protected BeanNameGenerator getBeanNameGenerator() {
        return this.qualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator;
    }
}
```

And the generator:

```
public class QualifiedNameAnnotationBeanNameGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {

    @Override
    protected String buildDefaultBeanName(BeanDefinition definition) {
        String qualifiedName = definition.getBeanClassName();
        return Introspector.decapitalize(qualifiedName);
    }
}
```

With this setup, common class names that are in different packages are automatically recognized as being different and the correct one gets injected.